# Write vs. Writelines of text to a file in R

Tags: r, string, text

In R, **write** and **writelines** seem to behave the same when I write normal text strings to a text file. 
Is there any distinction between them with respect to any specific scenario?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just writing out character vectors, you probably won't notice a difference.

While `writeLines` expects a character vector, `write()` tries to print any atomic vector via `cat()`. It also does some line wrapping by default

```
write(1:10, "")
# 1 2 3 4 5
# 6 7 8 9 10

writeLines(1:10)
# Error in writeLines(1:10) : invalid 'text' argument
```